# 20.04 LTS Wired Connection Fails at startup

Tags: networking

When I boot, the wired connection icon in the status bar shows a question mark. I find that I have an IP address and the correct DNS server. However, DNS lookups fail. I can ping the gateway though.

If I merely cycle the connection off, then reconnect again, it connects and works just fine.

Why doesn't it connect correctly at startup?

**Edit to add:**

I don't believe I tinkered with network management in any way. Output of journalctl -fu NetworkManager shows:

```
NetworkManager[1543]: <warn>  [1617130190.0057] dns-sd-resolved[5da5f9a7fdf7fdf7]: send-updates failed to update systemd-resolved: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Invalid DNS server address
```

But why?!

Comment: Installed any other network manager? Looks like two processes compete with each other. `journalctl -u NetworkManager` will list what happened. Add the infos to your question

Comment: @kanehekili Added the error from journalctl, but I have no idea why it's occurring. I'd just like to use DHCP and DNS from my router. It's bizarre because simply disabling / enabling the wired connection fixes it immediately after each boot.

Comment: It says `Invalid DNS server address` - so I assume you've got it in your /etc/hosts file. It might resolve to an alternate DNS server after reenabled. - and try the other command, I've made a mistake in my first post - sorry about that

Comment: Contents of /etc/hosts (which I didn't change):
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 mycomputer

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

Comment: With the -u option I found the same invalid DNS error, but also:
"ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist"
and
"Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate"

Comment: By the way, the IPv4 DNS setup generated no error, but the IPv6 one did